SQL Server Management Studio and Razor pages
I am following the tutorial of Razor pages which is provided by the official Microsoft site. The tutorial guide me to build a web app of that manages a database of movies https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio
And I am using SQL Server Management Studio
My question: How can I configure the project of Razor Pages web app to create the database in a way that gives me the opportunity to see the DB in Management Studio.
I tried to connect to this SQL server
servers connected to the project
but i can't see the database of the project in Management Studio

This tutorial uses Entity Framework, which is an ORM. If you follow all the steps, in the appconfig.json file you'll see a connection string. In this tutorial it's called: RazorPagesMovieContext. Simply point SSMS to the address in the connection string. Entity Framework takes care of creating all the tables.

We shall have connection string like

"DefaultConnection":
"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebAppDefIdentity-xxxx;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

Then in SSMS, we can connect to the database by adding server name as (localdb)\mssqllocaldb and choosing Windows Authentication. Then we can see the database.

